# I am trying to deploy my docker image from ACR to AKS. The pods are getting created properly but getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT through external IP

Tags: nestjs, azure-aks, acr

The same deployment and service yaml files are working properly when I am using a standard image from docker like nginx and set it's containerPort to default port of nginx i.e. 80 but when I am changing it's container port to 8080 then also I am getting the same issue.

My deployment.yaml file -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-test-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-test-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-test-container
        image: javapoccr.azurecr.io/sushant-saurav/my-nest-app-with-docker
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-details
```

My service.yaml -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-test-service
  labels:
    app: my-test-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-test-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two quick things that I would check/verify:

1. Is the test app configured to listen on 8080?  The containerPort/targetPort should match what the app is configured to listen on.
2. Ensure that you have the most recent image.  Without a tag, you are using :latest.  But if you update that, the imagePullPolicy will not pull the new image, if it has an older one.  I'd recommend changing the imagePullPolicy to `Always`

-Dave

Comment: Thanks Dave...the issue was of imagePullPolicy only...it's working now...thanks again